# Swift Firebase Login Registration auth

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

So when I first the page up I've kept it simple 2 text fields (email & password) 1 lbl 2 buttons (login register). Initially when I started out testing it everything worked when there was a problem an alert would pop up and tell you the problem, or you would be segue to next page based on button press and auth being complete.

But now every time I open the app to run code deeper inside no matter what I type I can sign in with the wrong password, or sign in with a previous email address even though previously these would both present errors. I have rebuilt this page numerous times over the week and decided to also add a get photo function from the users profile page.

Whenever I run the app and press a button I get this in the console:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

I figure this is the problem because there is an error with the registration but the user is allowed to continue regardless. I've looked it up googled it read all the documentation I can find and even messed about trying and failing to put in a task structure.

PS I moved away from error label to use alerts hoping they would force a stop in the code

```
   @IBAction func registerBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    if emailTextField.text! == "" || passwordTextField.text == "" {
        displayAlert(title: "Error", message: "Please Enter Your EMail Address & Choose A Password")
    } else {
        if let email = emailTextField.text {
            if let password = passwordTextField.text {
        //Create User
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

     //   Auth.auth().createUserAndRetrieveData(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    self.displayAlert(title: "Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
                    } else {
                        print("Registration Successful")
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "registrationSegue", sender: nil)
                    }
            self.login()
            })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What self.login does?

Comment: When I first put it in there I got an error. The suggested edit was self.login() so I changed this and the error was removed. So the login should automatically run after the registration is complete in my understanding. It would produce an error without self.

Answer (score 0):

```
if error != nil {
   // show your alert 
}
```

You don’t need an else statement on authenticating your users. so delete that line

Also, if you’re presenting a view controller that’s supposed to be accessible by authenticated users.

Please try:

```
let HomePage = HomePageController() // Change this to your viewcontroller name
self.present(HomePage, animated: true,     completion: nil)
```

Comment: Many thanks I will try that later on and let you know how it goes, but do you know if this will help resolve the auth issue?

Comment: My Auth problem is that the user never gets Authenticated. Can type any email registered or not and will perform Login, same problem with Registration. Firebase logs any new user and any user logged in even as far as uploading a profile photo so its all linked. I just cannot get it to Auth.

Answer (score 0):

### swift 4 - Xcode 9.1

```
 func signUP(){
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailIdTextField.text!, password: passworTextField.text!) { (user, error) in
            print(user?.email)
        }
    }

func signIn(){
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in
        print(user?.uid)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

```
//creating user with email password authentication

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextfield.text!, password: passwordTextfield.text!) { (user, error) in
        // completion handler
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        } else {
            //success
            print("Registration Sucessful")

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToChat", sender: self)
        }
    }
```